# Share Power BI dashboard in SharePoint without pro account

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I have embedded a Power BI dashboard in SharePoint, but only a few users in the company who have activated pro account can see the dashboard, other users get permission denied error.

It doesn't make sense to ask every employee in the organization to activate their Microsoft trial pro account for Power BI to be able to see the dashboard.

Is there any way I can share a dashboard for everyone without asking them to activate their pro account?

Answer (score 2):

For others to see the shared report in Share Point, they will need a Power BI Pro licence. Depending on the number of users, you could use Power BI Embedded, EM Sky's. This will allow your free user to become read only users. The first tier is about the same cost as 70-80 Pro licenses. However depending on the demands of your report's it may not be sufficient and have to purchase higher levels of the embedded service.